# passing variable to jQuery from same Class

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have googled for 2days so far :) Not finding the right answer yet. So expert help is needed.
I am writing the webpage, where I use php and mysql. On the webpage, it display list of products. Next to each product there is a button called "Compare". When user press the button, it should pop up the dialog box and ask user to enter some info then user click submit or cancel in the dialog box. When user click submit in the dialog box, it should take user to another page, where he will be displayed with information he is looking for (hopefully)....

For dialog box I am using jQuery-ui dialog box. The challenge I am facing is when user click on "Compare" button, I need to pass the product information to dialog box. Because all the product info are extracted from mysql and loop with php to display, they all have same class. eg
product 1Compare
product 2Compare
So how do i know which product_info i need to pass? I thought of adding attribute to button and product info with number to distinguish which one is selected, then i need to have multiple multiple dialog function attached to each button.

Any thought will be much appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable to store the index.

When we click on any button, we will check it's index and store in it.

After opening the popup or just before showing the popup, access this index. Using this index, access the division in which the product contains. Get required details from there. Update data in dialog box. Show dialog box.

Also clear global variable when you close the dialog box.

You can get more information about index here : http://api.jquery.com/index/

Friends, please suggest better solutions if any.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, here how I did it and seems passing the product info.

Comment: OK, here how I did it and seems passing the product info. I added name attribute in button

Compare

then I get the value of attribute when button is press

$(this).attr('name')

.. here is another question, say I got all the variable in the dialog box, now user clicks on submit, I need to send him to the other page with those info,http://comparison.com?product_info=product1&otherstuff=stuff , how can I redirect?